# The question about second isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is a group and $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $K \leqslant G$, and $N_1 \leqslant N$, $N_1 \trianglelefteq G$,  then can we say $NK/N_1 \approxeq K/K \cap N_1$?

Answer (score 0):

No; suppose, for instance, that $N = G$, and $N_1$ is the trivial subgroup. Then your statement says that $G \cong K$.

Comment: if nis not equal G and $N_1$ is not trivial, is correct?

Comment: No, it still is not. There are some weird edge cases where your formula happens to be true, but I would recommend taking a step back and wondering how you arrived at this formula, and whether it makes any real sense. For example, did you have an isomorphism in mind?

Comment: ys, in my problem, $G$ is a group and $N $ is normal in $G$ and $K$ is a subgrop of $G$ and $N_1$ is a subgroup of $N$ s st $N_1$ is normal, then i need tofind an isomorphism with $NK/N_1$

Comment: I would recommend rereading the problem carefully, because as you've asked it, it is false in "most" instances. (There might also be a typo in the problem.)

Comment: is this correct? $G/N$ is isomorphism to$(G/H)(H/N)$?(suppose $H$ is normal in $G$ and $N$ is normal in $H$)

Comment: What group is $(G/H)(H/N)$? We have that $G/H \cong (G/N)/(H/N)$, if that is what you mean.

Comment: my means is product

Comment: There is no natural product of $G/H$ and $H/N$. We could keep talking here, but I think you would be better served by taking another look at whatever material you are reading.

Comment: ok thanks im so sorry